# Reversing string in C using for loop

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C and I don't understand why my code isn't working. The aim is simply just to reverse a string.

```
char word[20];
int i, len;

printf("Enter word: ");
    scanf("%s", &word);

len = strlen(word);

printf("String reversed: "); 
for (i = len-1; i >= 0; i--){
    printf("%s", word[i]);
}
```

Comment: What is `word[i]`? What is the format `"%s"` supposed to print? Which format is used to print single characters?

Comment: `printf("%s", word[i]);` -> `putchar(word[i]);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude word[i] is supposed to hold the string inputted by a user, and %s is the format specifier for a string

Comment: `word[i]` is a single `char`.   The `%s` format tells `printf()` that it is printing a string (a set of `char`s, not a single `char`).   That difference causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: There should be a compiler warning emitted

Comment: @PSkocik that worked but I don't understand how? I thought 'putchar' and 'scanf' had the same functions.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - A compiler warning is not required.   Some compilers do it (quality of implementation, as an aid for the programmer) but they are not actually required to do so.

Comment: Just change `printf("%s", word[i]);` to `printf("%c", word[i]);`. You are printing characters, not strings

Comment: `word` contains a null-terminated byte string. `word[i]` is a single character (one `char`) from that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

> ```
> printf("%s", word[i]);
> ```

%s is a wrong format because you write a character, not a string

Out of that :

- the natural type for an index is `size_t`not *int*, use `size_t`for both *i* and *len*, and in that case change the loop to use index without supposing it can be negative
- if the input string has more than 19 characters *scanf* will write out of *word* with an undefined behavior, limit the size using the format %19s (19 rather than 20 to have the place for the ending null character)
- *word* is an array, do not use a '&' to give its address in *scanf*
- check the result of *scanf* if you want to detect EOF
- flush the output writing a newline after the loop

So a possible way is :

```
char word[20];

printf("Enter word: ");
if (scanf("%19s", word) == 1) {   
  printf("String reversed: "); 

  for (size_t i = strlen(word); i != 0; i--){
    printf("%c", word[i-1]);
  }
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: When looping in reverse, with a condition of `i >= 0` it is necessary to use a `signed` typr (e.g. `int`).   With an `unsigned` type (like `size_t`) the condition is always true, and the loop never ends (and gives undefined behaviour).

Comment: @Peter you are right, I edited my answer to change the loop

Comment: Why not use putchar() instead of printf()?

Comment: @BjornA. I reused the _printf_ to indicate the change to the OP even to use a _printf_ is very expensive for nothing to write only one character, so I do not use _printf_ again for the newline :-) WHat do you mean about "doesn't handle empty strings well" ? I manage them well .. I mean as I want

Comment: @BjornA. you edited your remark (after I answer to all of it) but you did not undo your DV supposing it was you, why ?

Comment: @bruno I just had a "senior moment" with that brief loop-comment. All my bad. I didn't downvote anything, btw. I upvoted your comment. That was me.

Comment: @BjornA. ah ok, thank you for answering and sorry for my wrong supposition :-)